# Potential jurors in a state election fraud scheme-conflict of interest?

Tags: united-states, jury, voting, conflict-of-interest

Obviously this question was inspired by recent events in the United States, specifically the state of Georgia.   It applies more generally though to any such case.   I thought that in order to be a juror in a case, you couldn't have a personal interest in the case as that would be a conflict.

Example:  Company A is suing Company B,   I own a bunch of stock in Company A,  I would have an obvious personal bias as to who wins the case.

Since state level crimes are prosecuted in the state they happen and potential jurors are eligible voters,   would this make it impossible for anyone who voted in the election to serve on such a jury as they would obviously prefer their side to win?   You couldn't have a change of venue as it is a state level crime and everyone in the state is involved.

So, would they have to find a jury of 12 nonvoters,  or would they ignore this and just ask if jury members would swear to put aside their personal feelings about who should win?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Since state level crimes are prosecuted in the state they happen and potential jurors are eligible voters, would this make it impossible for anyone who voted in the election to serve on such a jury as they would obviously prefer their side to win?"

No.

A conflict of interest is a particularized and personal interest in the case that is different from an interest of a member of the general public or of a voter or of a taxpayer in general. Someone who wouldn't have standing to bring a case will generally not have a conflict of interest for purposes of being a juror.